# Supporting non-ascii characters in Postgres full text (english)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, unicode

We're implementing Postgres full-text search. While the bulk of the text is normal English, there are a number of place names which include diacriticals (ñ,á,ó, etc)

More specifically, there are words like `cañon` -- I want to make sure that users who type `canon` also get matches for `cañon`.

Is there specific support for this? Or is the solution simply to manually manage the specific special cases using a thesaurus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unaccent` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html), either by pre-processing the text with `unaccent` function, or creating your own text search configuration. For instance (based on the example on [`unaccent`'s doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html)):

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_conf ( COPY = english );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_conf
    ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word
    WITH unaccent, english_stem;
```

So you can match it:

```
mydb=> SELECT to_tsvector('english','cañon'), to_tsvector('my_conf', 'cañon');
 to_tsvector | to_tsvector 
-------------+-------------
 'cañon':1   | 'canon':1
(1 row)

mydb=> SELECT
mydb->     to_tsvector('english','cañon') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'cañon'),
mydb->     to_tsvector('english','canon') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'canon'),
mydb->     to_tsvector('english','cañon') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'canon'),
mydb->     to_tsvector('english','canon') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'cañon'),
mydb->     to_tsvector('my_conf','cañon') @@ to_tsquery('my_conf', 'cañon'),
mydb->     to_tsvector('my_conf','canon') @@ to_tsquery('my_conf', 'canon'),
mydb->     to_tsvector('my_conf', 'cañon') @@ to_tsquery('my_conf', 'canon'),
mydb->     to_tsvector('my_conf', 'canon') @@ to_tsquery('my_conf', 'cañon');
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------
 t        | t        | f        | f        | t        | t        | t        | t
(1 row)
```

See the last query, I'm matching combinations of `cañon` and `canon`, when using `english` configuration (first 4 columns) will only match if both are the same (first 2 ones), but `my_conf` configuration (last 4 columns) will match in all of them.